# Here SDK - Android Navigate Edition - Is there a method to remove all map objects in mapscene?

Tags: here-api

I want to remove all objects in my map scene, include MapPolyline, MapMarker, MapPolygon, MapCluster, etc.

I had tried to find a method in Navigate Edition SDK, but I only found such of the method in Premiun Edition SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anywhere you create a MapPolyline, MapMarker, MapPolygon, MapCluster, etc. you must save to some variable. For example:

```swift
// All Markers (track origin, destination & stops MapMarkers)
var allMarkers: [MapMarker] = []

/// Generic function to add custom map market
func addCircleMapMarker(geoCoordinates: GeoCoordinates, imageName: String) {
    guard let image = UIImage(named: imageName)?.resizedTo(size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)), let imageData = image.pngData() else {
        return
    }
    
    let mapMarker = MapMarker(at: geoCoordinates, image: MapImage(pixelData: imageData, imageFormat: ImageFormat.png))
    self.mapView.mapScene.addMapMarker(mapMarker)

    self.allMarkers.append(mapMarker) // < Here you track your marker when add to map
}

/// Clear all waypoint map markers
private func clearWaypointMapMarker() {
    // Here you remove all markers from the map
    for mapMarker in self.allMarkers {
        self.mapView.mapScene.removeMapMarker(mapMarker)
    }
    
    self.allMarkers.removeAll()
}
```